# suspending further execution while showing alert dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a method like

```
public void testing(){
getConfirmation() //this shows alert dialog for user confirmation
showListview() //just populate list view
}
```

I need to wait till the user gives response to alert dialog and then i want to execute showListview() method. But now, immediately second method called after getConfirmation() method. Whether i have to set any property to make alert dialog to suspend the further execution.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how android dialogs work. You can't just stop the thread execution and wait for a user confirmation. You should use listeners instead. Something like this:

```
public void testing() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            showListview();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", null);
    builder.show();
}
```